# protractor does not recognize '\' at uploading a file

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I've been reading a few answers to this and implemented one of those. Here is my code:

```
    var path = require('path');
    var fileToUpload = "C:\Users\patricio.lussenhoff\Desktop\test.txt",
    absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    var type3 = browser.element(by.css('[type="file"]'));
    type3.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

The protractor apparently is not recognizing the slashes (I've tried '/' way too)
and the control shows like this:

[here is the example I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikIoP.png)

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var fileToUpload = "C:\\Users\\patricio.lussenhoff\\Desktop\\test.txt";    
var type3 = browser.element(by.css('[type="file"]'));
type3.sendKeys(fileToUpload);
```

This way you don't need to use 'path.resolve' because you are passing the complete and correct path.

Comment: I tried that and the textbox is only displaying 'text.txt' so it didn't work. Any other option?

Comment: It usually happens when the file is not found. Make sure you can access the file with the path you are setting. Use `console.log(fileToUpload)` and use this output to access the file (using windows explorer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OS Use single forward slash(Linux, Unix, etc.,) or double backward slash(Windows) to read files:

```
var fileToUpload = "C:/Users/patricio.lussenhoff/Desktop/test.txt",
var fileToUpload = "C:\\Users\\patricio.lussenhoff\\Desktop\\test.txt",
```

Comment: I tried that and the textbox is only displaying 'text.txt' so it didn't work. Any other option?

Comment: Windows seven. Thanks for checking this out.

Comment: You can you AutoIT but when you have input tag, sendKeys should work and that is easy and elegant solution rather than using AutoIT. Can you check file exits on particular location what you are specifying?
Change the location "patricio.lussenhoff" may be "." causing issue.